# Apache Tomcat error http status 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

To be honest i am a learner and this is my first ever servlet program.
I made the basic servlet and intalled tomcat version 6 and even tomcat version 8.
the server starts up correctly and i am able to see the tomcat start up page on going to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but after logging to tomcat manager when i click on my folder name it gives me an error saying

http status 404-/online/ (online is my folder created in webapps)

type Status report

message /online/

description The requested resource is not available.

here's my codes

web.xml-> (in folder online->WEB-INF)

```
- <web-app>
- <servlet>
  <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

FirstServlet.java->

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

class FirstServelet implements Servlet
{
    public void init(ServletConfig config)
    {

    }

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out;
        out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("hello");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>MY First Servlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<marquee>ban ja tar pls</marquee>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }

    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void destroy ()
    {

    }
}
```

please resolve the 404 error

Comment: you are hitting `http://localhost:8080/online` Right?

Comment: `extends HttpServlet` to create your own servlet instead of `implements Servlet`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't `welcome-file-list`, I think the default page is index.html which I suppose is not there in you folder. You can provide any html or jsp file as default file but NOT a servlet as below.

```
<welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>myfile.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

You can access your servlet by hitting `http://localhost:8080/online/FirstServlet` URL.

You can create a default page which will redirect to FirstServlet i.e.

**myfile.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost:8080/online/FirstServlet" />
```

And also what @Braj said in the comment `extend HttpServlet` instead of `implement Servlet`.

**Edit**

You have a typo in servlet name. change the servlet name to `FirstServlet` from `FirstServelet`.

Comment: Thanks for support but u just mentioned welcome file list. This is a totally new concept for me and the servlet does not run even by calling http://localhost:8080/online/FirstServelet

Comment: Updated my answer. There was an extra "e" in you servlet and also in url. hit http://localhost:8080/online/FirstServlet If that does not work then do what @Braj suggested. extend HttpServlet instead of implement Servlet.