# Apache Tomcat returns 404 error for Web Application

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, tomcat

I have a Spring MVC application WAR file deployed in `${catalina_home}/webapps`. Let's say the name of the WAR is `abc.war` and suppose, after tomcat unpacks the WAR and creates a folder `abc` in `webapps` folder, there is file named inside `abc`, in path `app/abc.js`.After running the tomcat server, I typed 'http://localhost:8090/abc/app/abc.js` on the browser. This returns an 404 error on the browser.

```
Operating System: Windows 7
Apache Tomcat: version 7, running on PORT 8090.
Java version: 8
```

This setup is the same on all other systems with the team of developers I work with and it works for them on their system. But it does not work on my system.
Please can anybody help me with an insight why this could happen and possibly a fix will be great respite. thanks.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849700/apache-tomcat-error-http-status-404

Comment: There is a possibility that even if the webapp is unpacked from war and you see the directory for your war, it might not have been properly deployed. Check your logs for any error or you can deploy `manager` webapp to see the state of your webapp.

Comment: Can you post the application structure?

Answer (score -2):

Please find below point will effected on application

1. Database use access
2. Set proper Environment variable (like. JDK,MAVEN)
3. check CPU and memory usages of other process
4. check thread dumps

Hope so its will help you :)

Comment: Is that the answer to the above question?